# jquery store value in array and compare differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working with `autocomplete` and it's going splendidly however I can't seem to remove the values that have already been selected. I have tried to `alert(usedTags)` and it is definitely storing the information in `usedTags`. I've also tried `alert($(availableTags).not(usedTags).get());` and it is showing me the difference that I should be seeing as the source....but when I try to add another value, it's still showing me the entire `availableTags` array. Is there something I'm missing when adding the source? Is the source added only when the function is opened on the first `autocomplete`? If so, how do I get it to update each time I've added a value... Thanks!

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "jimmy",
        "barbie",
        "belle",
        "dylan",
        "tony",
        "lonnie"
    ];
    var usedTags = [];

    $("#labels").autocomplete({
        source: $(availableTags).not(usedTags).get(),
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(e, ui){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<span class = 'added' id = '"+ ui.item.id + "'>").html( ui.item.value).appendTo($(this).parent().find('.addvals'));
            usedTags.push(ui.item.value);
            $(this).val('');
            //alert(usedTags);
            //alert($(availableTags).not(usedTags).get());
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
For the purposes of this question, I've simplified my `availableTags` array but I know that getting the id in the span would require a more complex array. Just in case that stands out to anyone.

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: problem with `$(availableTags).not(usedTags).get(),`

Comment: I'm trying to make a fiddle right now but it's not rendering correctly. What do you see as the problem? I'll have a jsf up in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the `Array.prototype.filter()` method.

```
availableTags.filter(function(tag) {
    return (usedTags.indexOf(tag) === -1);
});
```